# multiple tables using date schema vs single table using date index

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm using Postgres to perform analysis on financial data (trades and quotes).

A common use case for me is to query trades / quotes / both in a specific timestamp range.

The way I've currently implemented the db structure, is keeping a schema per trading day (E.g. schema_20180821) which hold a quotes and trades table with the relevant data (the timestamp column is indexed).

So, this is good for me in a sense where:

1. It's "more organized" (my opinion).
2. explicit access to specific dates is easier.
3. If I decide to remove specific dates for any reason, I don't make a mess of the Id primary key.
4. different schemas - locks are in schema level and not in table level.

But now I got like 90 days of data (which are 90 schemas) and I found that it's a maintenance pain to in addition a query to cross different dates is complex (having it on one table with date column would have been easier to query, but I guess slower to perform).

My question is if there is a more optimal way to organize the db structure.

Tables DDL below (single trades holds table approx ~2M rows , single quotes table holds approx ~120M rows)

```
CREATE TABLE md_20180727.trades
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  date date,
  symbol character varying(20),
  exchange_time timestamp without time zone,
  last numeric,
  last_size integer,
  CONSTRAINT trades_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE md_20180727.quotes
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  date date,
  symbol character varying(20),
  exchange_time timestamp without time zone,
  bid numeric,
  bid_size integer,
  ask numeric,
  ask_size integer,
  status character varying(10),
  spread numeric,
  mid numeric,
  CONSTRAINT quotes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the data volume - thousends, millions or more rows?
Second why you care about "PK mess" - how looks you typical queries?

Comment: That is an interesting way to do what best can be done with [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE).

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek added table sizes. I care because It helps me cross rows according to their specific order.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe how will partitioning be affected when a day / partial day data is removed?

Comment: @Y.S it will be good when you read about partitioning concept in Postgres manual. This is well explained. I too feel just like LaurenzAlbe that this is indeed a thing for partitioning. You can drop a partition table and that's just about it.

Comment: @KamilG.thanks, I will definitely dig in that direction, would be happy to hear additional suggestions if any.

Comment: @Y.S I do not understand the question. Partitioning is not affected by removing data, it *facilitates* removing data (if a whole partition can be dropped, that is).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe pardon my english, I meant to ask if the data / indexing / table / query performance will be affected from data removal when choosing to partition the table. Like any architecture I assume partitioning has it's pros and cons and I'm interested in understanding what pros and cons will I face according to the current structure and data size. will joins be affected differently, etc.

Comment: The only problem with partitioning is that when you insert/update/delete by parent table you lock access to all child tables.
It is pain in the ass if you have system where mass operations during day are common.

Comment: @Y.S Main pros are - 1.Easy acceess to all data by parent table , 2.Partitiong will redirect your statments only to proper child table(s) according to your where conditions so reading records should be faster then from one big table with indexing.
CONS -  1. INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE done on the main table will lock access to all child tables. 2. Every time you want to make new partition table for next range you will have to create it (POSTGRE partitioning is not a real partitionig like in Oracle, but rather sort of  communication between parent and child tabels).

Comment: Also you have separte PK for each child table - sometimes it is PROS sometimes it is CONS.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek thanks, noted.

Comment: My comments are for version before 10. In 10 you have real partitioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want partitioning!  Read more about it in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

Having multiple tables with the same data structure is almost never a good idea.  As you have found, querying multiple days of data is . . . well a nightmare.

Here are my reactions to your points:

> 1. It's "more organized" (my opinion).

Not at all.  A zillion parallel tables is not more organized.  A single table is cleaner both aesthetically and from a maintenance perspective.

> 2. explicit access to specific dates is easier.

Changing a table name is "easier" than adding a `where` clause?  Even if I grant that they are equivalent for one date, multiple dates is clearly painful wtih multiple tables.

> 3. If I decide to remove specific dates for any reason, I don't make a mess of the Id primary key.

I don't understand what "mess of the id primary key" means.  This is admittedly an advantage over an unpartitioned table.  Deleting rows from a single table incurs a lot of overhead for logging and locking.  However, removing a partition is almost as easy as dropping a table.

> different schemas - locks are in schema level and not in table level.

This is a valid reason.  With a single table solution, there are options for this:

- Using a JSON column to store flexible additional data columns.
- Altering the table for the new columns.

However, changes to data are (presumably) quite rare, so I would be cautious in using this to guide the overall approach.

There are other downsides to multiple tables:

- Multiple tables are probably going to have more partially filled data pages and index pages, running up memory usage.
- Multiple tables make it hard to look at data over time -- which is probably why you are storing historical time series anyway.
- Multiple tables require more efforts for backup and recovery.
- Multiple tables require dynamic SQL for generalization in stored procedures and applications.

There are valid reasons for using the "table multiplicity" approach.  The ones that I can think of are:

- Significant changes to the schema over time.
- Different user-level access requirements.